# reason: '+[UIImage didReceiveMemoryWarning:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1a0bd1798'

Tags: ios

Iam using uimageview in tableview, before adding uiimage view in tableview the Application get crash due to this problem ( +[UIImage didReceiveMemoryWarning:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1a0bd1798 ).

Comment: Could you give the call stack also when it crashes?

Comment: turn on zombies, seems more like a memory issue

Comment: @Larme  when application run in device it get crash,in simulator running perfect.